# Connecting to MSSQL database with ADO and PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, ado

I have a MSSQL database. I wrote a php page to connect and retreive data from it. The code works on my localhost.

```
$strCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=local;database=test;uid=sa;pwd=go;";

$strAlias = "GEORGE";

$strSql = "SELECT LINK FROM LINKS WHERE ALIAS = '" . $strAlias . "'";

$Con = new COM ("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$Rs = new COM ("ADODB.Recordset") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$Con->open($strCon);
$Rs->open($strSql,$Con,1,3);

if (!$Rs->EOF && !$Rs->BOF) {
 $strTargetLink = $Rs->Fields['LINK'];
 echo $strTargetLink;
}

$Rs->Close();
$Con->Close();
$Rs = null;
$Con = null;
```

When I run this code on the server, I receive some error? when echo $strTargetLink; row is executed, word

> Object

is received on the sent html page and also in the source code of that page.

I am running PHP on IIS as a FastCGI application. Both PHP 4.4.7 and 5.2.6 are supported.

Any ideas? What does this **Object** text mean?

Thanks.

Instead of using echo, I now tried

```
var_dump($strTargetLink);
```

and received the information

> object(COM)(1) { [0]=> resource(3) of type (COM) }

Comment: Please always quote the exact error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

try using [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) instead of echo.  it will at least give you more information about the object contained in `$strTargetLink`.

Comment: thanks. i tried it and received: object(COM)(1) { [0]=> resource(3) of type (COM) } I am not a php programmer. Normally i use asp but I need just one php page to run. What does this new code mean? Anything I can do now?

Comment: i'm not familiar with using adodb in php, so i'd say just keep vardumping the objects, like vardump($strTargetLink[0])

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and now it works. So just in case you would like to connect with ADO, I am writing what I have done.

Instead of

```
$strTargetLink = $Rs->Fields['LINK'];
```

I wrote

```
$strTargetLink = $Rs->Fields(0);
```